# Getting TP-Link TL-WN722N to work with Kali

Tags: wifi, drivers, vmware, kali-linux, modprobe

I am trying to get the TP-Link TL-WN722N USB WIFI adapter to work with Kali Linux in VMWare Player.

I was able to get it to work outside a VM in Elementary OS (Ubuntu based) by following the instructions here: http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless Making wlunload didn't work but it still used the adapter just fine.

In Kali in a VM though, I follow the same instructions and get to modprobe and get this:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo modprobe ath9k
ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Exec format error
```

I checked the gcc version and it seems to match the one used to compile the kernel (I compared /proc/version to gcc -v)

Making wlunload still fails:

```
kali@kali:~/backports-3.18.1-1$ sudo make wlunload
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `wlunload'.  Stop.
make: *** [wlunload] Error 2
```

lsusb confirms it is there, and iwconfig shows no wireless connections.

```
kali@kali:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
kali@kali:~$ sudo iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Rebooting, unplugging and replugging the adapter, and recompiling don't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get my wifi card TP-Link TL-WN722N to work in Kali-Linux VMware 12](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391278/how-can-i-get-my-wifi-card-tp-link-tl-wn722n-to-work-in-kali-linux-vmware-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably should have tried this first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I also followed the instructions linked above, but it may have worked without that.

At least it works now!