# How can I get my wifi card TP-Link TL-WN722N to work in Kali-Linux VMware 12

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, vmware

[image: **Screenshot of VM ware kali linux wifi**]

As shown in the screenshot , i tried lsusb and iwconfig, none of them displayed my wifi adapter. I tried switching the USB ports and restarting VM. Performed the updates and upgrades. Its working on the host OS(windows 8).

Answer (score 1):

Your USB wifi already listed through `lsusb` command the ID `2357:010c` is IDvendor and the IDproduct of the TP-Link TL-WN722N USB wifi.

2 ways to install the driver :

The wired connection is required

1) open the terminal and run the following command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

then

```
apt-get install dkms git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
dkms add ./rtl8188eu
dkms build 8188eu/1.0
dkms install 8188eu/1.0
modprobe 8188eu
```

2) by compiling the source

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Use the command `apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install the appropriate `linux-headers` pacakge , then run :

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make
make install
modprobe 8188eu
```

Comment: Thanks GAD3R..
but i am getting a certificate error while cloning.

root@kali:~# git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
Cloning into 'rtl8188eu'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Comment: @Josco see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824116/5848185

Comment: `apt-get dkms git` responds with `unable to locate package dkms` then `Package 'git' has no installation candidate`

Comment: never mind my sources file was empty (see this link if anyone else experiences this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465465/apt-get-upgrade-wont-work-on-kali )

Comment: @MarkDeven check your sources.list https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Answer (score 0):

This install worked for me as root (use `sudo -s` at the beginning)

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install bc
rmmod r8188eu.ko
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus 
cd rtl8188eus
echo "blacklist r8188eu.ko" > "/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf"
make
make install
modprobe 8188eu
reboot
```

if `make` doesn't work reboot & try again

I hope that it works for you too